# Javascript error with dot before a number

Tags: javascript

I'm making a bot with discord.js and node.js and I have a problem with a variable where I have to put a number between two dots

```
var supplies1 = r.body.response.suppliesUsage.0.usages;
```

The IDE is highlighting ".0" and saying that ',' is expected.

Comment: What are you expecting `suppliesUsage.0.usages` to do? Do you mean `suppliesUsage[0].usages`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use object dot notation starting with a number. So instead of `r.body.response.suppliesUsage.0.usages` you need to do `r.body.response.suppliesUsage[0].usages`

[Dot Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation)